# How To get text between 2 strings?

Tags: c#, regex

String is given below from which i want to extract the text.

String:

```
Hello Mr John and Hello Ms Rita
```

Regex

```
Hello(.*?)Rita
```

I am try to get text between 2 strings which "Hello" and "Rita" I am using the above given regex, but its is giving me

```
Mr John and Hello Ms
```

which is wrong.  I need only "Ms"  Can anyone help me out to write proper regex for this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
Hello((?:(?!Hello|Rita).)*)Rita
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uU2mN8/1)

The `(?:(?!Hello|Rita).)*` is the tempered greedy token that only matches text that is not `Hello` or `Rita`. You may add word boundaries `\b` if you need to check for whole words.

In order to get a `Ms` without spaces on both ends, use this [regex variation](https://regex101.com/r/uU2mN8/2):

```
Hello\s*((?:(?!Hello|Rita).)*?)\s*Rita
```

Adding the `?` to `*` will form a lazy quantifier `*?` that matches as few characters as needed to find a match, and `\s*` will match zero or more whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

To get the closest match towards ending word, let a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) dot in front of the initial word consume.

```
.*Hello(.*?)Rita
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dR3aI0/1)

Or without whitespace in captured: [`.*Hello\s*(.*?)\s*Rita`](https://regex101.com/r/hN5vD7/1)
Or with use of two capture groups: [`.*(Hello\s*(.*?)\s*Rita)`](https://regex101.com/r/vC0oQ7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `(.*?)` is picking up too much text because `.*` matches *any* string of characters. So it grabs everything from the first "Hello" to "Rita" at the end.

One easy way you could get what you want is with this regular expression:

```
Hello (\S+) Rita
```

`\S` matches any non-whitespace character, so `\S+` matches any consecutive string of non-whitespace characters, i.e. a single word.

This would be a bit more robust, allowing for multiple spaces or other whitespace between the words:

```
Hello\s+(\S+)\s+Rita
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP0tM7/1)

Comment: What is there are more words, with punctuation, between `Hello` and `Rita`, and another `Hello` in-between? Then, this approach will not work.

Comment: That is true, of course. I can imagine any number of other situations where this RE will fail, or where yours would fail as well. Given the simple problem OP presented, I tend to go for a simple solution. But it is valuable to see a variety of approaches to a problem, so the solution you posted is much appreciated. Of course to give a truly robust solution, we'd need a better idea of what other kinds of input strings might be encountered. With a single test string, we can only guess and try to find a compromise between robustness and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

you can use lookahead and lookbehind `(?<=Hello).*?(?=Rita)`